# You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm a little blocked here. 
I'm not new to tensorflow, even tho I did not work a lot with it.
But here's my problem :

I want to classify texts in 7 different categories, and for that I used the tfidf method to transform strings to numbers.
There, I transformed the sparse matrix into a dense one, which gives me a 2D matrix of shape (179, 482).
I split it into 150 obs training set and 29 obs testing set.
Then, I've setted up my model as follow :

```
'''
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Convolution 2D avec RELU
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 
def conv1d(x, W, b, name_conv, name_bias, name_relu, strides=1):
    tensor = tf.nn.conv1d(x, W, strides, padding="SAME", name=name_conv)
    tensor = tf.nn.bias_add(tensor,b, name=name_bias)
    return tf.nn.relu(tensor, name=name_relu)

'''
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pooling max
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 
def maxpool2d(x, name, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, [1, k, k, 1], [1, k, k, 1], padding="SAME", name=name)


'''
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modele du reseau convolutif :
CONV1-RELU-CONV2-RELU-FCL-Prediction
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''
def conv_net(x, poids, biais):
    # Mise en forme de l'image d'entree
    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 482, 1])

    conv1 = conv1d(x, poids['wconv1'], biais['bconv1'], name_conv='conv1', name_bias='bias1', name_relu='relu1')
    #conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2, name='pool1')

    conv2 = conv1d(conv1, poids['wconv2'], biais['bconv2'], name_conv='conv2', name_bias='bias2', name_relu='relu2')
    #conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2, name='pool2')

    # Mise en forme des activations de la seconde couche cachee pour l'entree de la couche completement connectee
    fcl = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, poids['wfcl'].get_shape().as_list()[0]], name='reshape')
    fcl = tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl, poids['wfcl']), biais['bfcl'], name='fcl')
    fcl = tf.nn.relu(fcl, name='relu3')

    # Dropout 
    #fcl = tf.nn.dropout(fcl, dropout, name='dropout')

    # Couche de sortie
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fcl, poids['out']), biais['out'], name='out')

    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ''' 
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Parametres du reseau
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '''
    learning_rate = 0.00001
    num_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 1
    dropout = 0.75 # ici probabilite de garder le neurone

    logs_path = "tensorflow_logs"

    data, targets = getData() 
    data = np.float32(data)
    targets = np.float32(targets)

    x_train = data[:150]
    y_train = targets[:150]

    x_test = data[150:]
    y_test = targets[150:]

    num_examples = x_train.shape[0] 
    num_input =x_train.shape[1]
    num_classes = y_train.shape[1]

    # Affichage des informations par pas de temps
    display_step = 10

    # Espaces reserves qui vont etre remplis par les tenseurs representant l'ensemble des images et des labels lors de l'apprentissage
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_input], name='data')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes], name='labels')
    #keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')   

    #Stockage des poids et biais dans des variables TF
    '''
    TODO : initialiser avec une loi normale des variables tensorFlow :
        - wconv1 et bcconv1 pour CONV1. wconv1 est un banc de 32 filtres 5*5*1. bconv1 a une taille adaptee
        - wconv2 et bconv2 pour CONV2. wcconv2 est un banc de 32 filtres 5*5*32*64. bconv2 a une taille adaptee
        - wfcl et bfcl pour la couche completement connectee : wfcl est un banc de filtres 7*7*64 a 1024 sorties. bfcl a une taille adaptee
        - out (poids et biais) ont une taille adaptee pour la classification des donnees MNIST
    '''

    poids = {
            'wconv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 1, 32])),
            'wconv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 32, 64])),
            'wfcl': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64, 1024])),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, num_classes]))
    }

    biais = {
            'bconv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
            'bconv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
            'bfcl': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
            'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
    }

    # Construction du modele
    pred = conv_net(x, poids, biais)
    print(pred.shape)

    # Fonction de perte et procedure d'optimisation
    #TODO : entropie croisee avec logits, algorithme d'optimisation ADAM
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Evaluation du modele
    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

    # Initialisation des variables
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    tf.summary.scalar("cost", cost)
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

    merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    # Creation d'une session TF pour executer le programme
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)

        train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path  + '/train', graph=tf.get_default_graph())
        test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path + '/test', graph=tf.get_default_graph())

        # Entrainement
        total_batch = int(num_examples/batch_size)
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            # Entrainement sur les batchs d'images
            for step in range (total_batch):
                perm = np.arange(num_examples)
                np.random.shuffle(perm)
                indices = perm[0:batch_size]
                batch_x = x_train[indices]
                batch_y = y_train[indices]
                _, summary = sess.run([optimizer, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                 y: batch_y})
                train_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch*total_batch+step)
                if step % display_step == 0:
                    loss, acc, summaryt = sess.run([cost, accuracy, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                     y: batch_y})
                    test_writer.add_summary(summaryt, epoch*total_batch+step)
                    print("Iteration " + str(epoch * total_batch + step) + ", Precision  = " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))

        # Test

        print("Test:", sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: x_test,
                                                     y: y_test}))
```

When I'm keeping my summaries, I get this error :

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'data' with dtype float and shape [?,482]

So, I'm a little lost, since when I remove the summaries as follow :

```
for step in range (total_batch):
            perm = np.arange(num_examples)
            np.random.shuffle(perm)
            indices = perm[0:batch_size]
            batch_x = x_train[indices]
            batch_y = y_train[indices]
            sess.run([optimizer], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                             y: batch_y})
            #train_writer.add_summary(summary, epoch*total_batch+step)
            if step % display_step == 0:
                loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                                 y: batch_y})
                #test_writer.add_summary(summaryt, epoch*total_batch+step)
                print("Iteration " + str(epoch * total_batch + step) + ", Precision  = " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
```

My model is learning (it learns pretty much nothing, but still it's doing somthing)

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong ?
I must confess that I've always worked with 4D arrays, mostly for image recognition, so this case is new for me.

Thanks for any good samaraitan that'll answer my question.

P.S. Sorry for french comments, but I'm sure you can still understand the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there's something I forgot to mention : I'm working with Spyder.

The error must come from there for I executed my program directly in Ubuntu's console and everything works just fine.

Closing it here.